# I need my javascript code to retrieve id by block of code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have a Javscript that can retrieve the id from onClick, but it only selects the first div with an id. The problem is that I have multiple unique id's that are generated in php and then saved in mysql database. The id's are unique but I need my onClick to retrieve the id in the div block.

```
 function postFunction() {
var i;
var x;
  for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++)
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("post")[0].getAttribute("id");
    //alert(this.id);
    alert(x);

}
```

Is there a way to select id per code block?

Comment: Post your HTML as well. And I don't see any `onclick` in your code!

Comment: Can describe _"Is there a way to select id per code block?"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have the jQuery tag in your question. Try this:

```
function postFunction() {
    var ids = []; //in case you need to have all ids;
    $('.post').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        ids.push(id); //Store the id in the array
        alert(id);
    });
    console.log(ids); //Show all ids.
}
```

Comment: I like your code, now I'm trying to narrow it down so that the button only grabs the id in the same div and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery will make life easier.

```
var h=[];
$("div").each(function(){
   h.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

alert(h);
You will get a array of all div ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
function postFunction() {
    var ids = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("post"), function(elem) {
        return elem.id
    });
    console.log(ids.join(", "));
}
```

Comment: Tried `js` at post ? Does `document.getElementsByClassName("post")` return an array that could be chained to `Array.prototype.map()` method ?

Comment: You're right, you need array.prototype.map, editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the elements, and then loop over them (currently your loop code doesn't do anything)

```
function postFunction() {

    var postEls = document.getElementsByClassName('post'),
        postElsCount = postEls.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < postElsCount; i++) {
        alert(postEls[i].id);
    }

}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Lta3e8/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will always ease such operations but you can also achieve the same using vanilla javascript. It takes effort & time because of cross browser support for javascript varies much but it's worth to give a try.

```
function postFunction() {
    var ids = [];
    var x = document.getElementByClassName('post');

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var temp = x[i].getAttribute("id");
        ids.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(ids)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of *all* HTML elements with the provided class name. In your loop, you are only ever alerting the *first* element returned at index `[0]`.

Try:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 1) {
    alert(x[i].getAttribute("id"));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div id="blah1" class="post"></div>
<div id="blah2" class="post"></div>
<div id="blah3" class="post"></div>
<div id="blah4" class="post"></div>
<div id="blah5" class="post"></div>
</html>
```